# Efficient way to compute a tensor

Tags: matlab, tensor

Suppose `c` is a d-dimensional vector. I want to compute the following third-order tensor
[image]

where `e_i` stands for the `i`th standard basis of the Euclidean space. Is there a efficient way to compute this? I am using the following for-loop and the Kruskal-tensor `ktensor` to compute it using the [tensor toolbox](http://www.sandia.gov/~tgkolda/TensorToolbox/index-2.5.html) managed by Sandia National Labs:

```
x=ktensor({c,c,c});
I=eye(d);

for i=1:d
    x=x+2*c(i)*ktensor({I(:,i),I(:,i),I(:,i)}
end

for i=1:d
    for j=1:d

         x=x- c(i)*c(j)*(ktensor({I(:,i),I(:,i),I(:,j)})+ktensor({I(:,i),I(:,j),I(:,i)})+ktensor({I(:,i),I(:,j),I(:,j)}))


    end
end
```

Comment: One thing you could try is the Parallel Computing Toolbox (aka `parfor`). Since there is no dependency between different `i` and `j` indices, you could calculate each terms in the summation in parallel.

Comment: @Yvon: How would the modified code with `parfor` look like? Is it much faster compared to the above? I am guessing it might be $d vs d^2$ speed up or something.

Comment: I will give you a sample code in a minute. It's not optimizing the code, but merely let the cpu run the each iteration on a separate thread, so they can be done at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility.

- I used an optimization for the second term, as it places values of `c` along the "diagonal" of the tensor.
- For the first term, there isn't much room for optimization, as it is a dense multiplication, so `bsxfun` seems appropriate.
- For the third term, I stick to `bsxfun`, but as the result is somewhat sparse, you may benefit from filling it "by hand" if the size of your matrix is large.

Here is the code:

```
dim = 10;
c = [1:dim]';
e = eye(dim);

x = zeros([dim, dim, dim]);
% initialize with second term
x(1:dim*(dim+1)+1:end) = 2 * c;
% add first term
x = x + bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@times, c, shiftdim(c, -1)), shiftdim(c, -2));
% add third term
x = x - sum(sum(bsxfun(@times, shiftdim(c*c',-3), ...
   bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@times, permute(e, [1, 3, 4, 2, 5]), permute(e, [3, 1, 4, 2, 5])), permute(e, [3, 4, 1, 5, 2])) +...
   bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@times, permute(e, [1, 3, 4, 2, 5]), permute(e, [3, 1, 4, 5, 2])), permute(e, [3, 4, 1, 2, 5])) +...
   bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@times, permute(e, [1, 3, 4, 5, 2]), permute(e, [3, 1, 4, 2, 5])), permute(e, [3, 4, 1, 2, 5]))), 5), 4);
```

**EDIT**

A much more efficient (esp. memory-wise) computation of the third term:

```
ec = bsxfun(@times, e, c);
x  = x - ...
  bsxfun(@times, ec, shiftdim(c, -2)) -...
  bsxfun(@times, c', reshape(ec, [dim, 1, dim])) -....
  bsxfun(@times, c, reshape(ec, [1, dim, dim]));
```

Comment: Excellent, the edited solution is a significant speed up compared to my method!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/) that is namely [`parfor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html) loops.

```
x=ktensor({c,c,c});
I=eye(d);

y = zeros(d,d,d, d);
parfor i=1:d
    y(:,:,:, i) = 2*c(i)*ktensor({I(:,i),I(:,i),I(:,i)};
end
x = x + sum(y, 4);

z = zeros(d,d,d, d,d);
parfor i=1:d
    for j=1:d % only one layer of parallelization is allowed
         z(:,:,:, i,j) = c(i)*c(j)*(ktensor({I(:,i),I(:,i),I(:,j)})+ktensor({I(:,i),I(:,j),I(:,i)})+ktensor({I(:,i),I(:,j),I(:,j)}));
    end
end
x = x - sum(sum(z, 5), 4);
x % is your result
```

It just runs the untouched `ktensor` commands but in separate threads, so the Toolbox takes care of running the code in parallel.

Because of the independence property of each iteration, which means, for example, `c_{i+1, j+1}` does not rely on `c_{i, j}`, this is possible.

Depending on the number of cores (and hyperthreading) of your system, there could be up to #-of-cores-times of speed-up.

Comment: The entry `z(i,j)` is initialized with zero but in the for-loops it stores a whole tensor?

Comment: @pikachuchameleon oops.

Comment: @pikachuchameleon So I got little knowledge from their webpage without actually getting the code. What is the dimension of variable `x` in your workspace? and what is `d`?

Comment: `x` is a `d*d*d` tensor and `d` is some natural number.  Suppose you have a tensor `T=a*a*a+b*b*b`, then the syntax `T=ktensor({[a,b],[a,b],[a,b]}` does exactly the same and it stands for Kruskal tensor.

Comment: Edited answer. `x` is supposed to be a d x d x d matrix, `y` contains all dimensions of `x` in the first three subscripts, then the forth for the loop. `z` does the same thing but contains two loop indices.